# Tikz circuit - Coordinates of terminals of components

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am drawing a schematic and I would like to specify the particular coordinates of terminals of the components.

For instance, in my drawing (source below), I would like the 'X' dot to be at the same height than the gate of M4. Similarly, I drew the dot below the drain of M6 with trials, but I would like to automatically adjust it to the absissa of the M6 drain and the ordinate of the M7 gate.

Is there a command that gives the absissa (or ordinate) of the terminal of a component ?

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\figHt{6};
\coordinate (ref_node1) at (2,0); 
\coordinate (ref_node2) at (8,0);
\coordinate (ref_node3) at (12,0);
\coordinate (ref_nodeT1) at ($(ref_node1)+(0,\figHt)$); 
\coordinate (ref_nodeT2) at ($(ref_node2)+(0,\figHt)$);
\coordinate (ref_nodeT3) at ($(ref_node3)+(0,\figHt)$);

\draw (ref_node1) node[nmos,anchor=source] (Mn0){}
  (ref_node1) ++(-1,2) node[nmos, anchor=source] (M1){}
  (ref_node1) ++(1,2) node[nmos, anchor=source, xscale=-1] (M2){}
  (ref_node2) node[nmos,anchor=source] (Mn1){}
  (ref_node2) ++(-1,2) node[nmos, anchor=source] (M3){}
  (ref_node2) ++(1,2) node[nmos, anchor=source, xscale=-1] (M4){}
  (ref_node3) node[nmos,anchor=source] (Mn2){}
  (ref_nodeT1) ++(-1,0) node[pmos, anchor=source, xscale=-1] (M5){}
  (ref_nodeT2) ++(-1,0) node[pmos, anchor=source] (M6){}
  (ref_nodeT3) ++(0,-1)node[pmos, anchor=source] (M7){} ;

\draw (M1.drain)-- (M5.drain) node[circ] -| (M5.gate) node[circ] -- (M6.gate);
\draw (M2.drain) |- (M7.gate);
\draw (M7.gate) -- ++(-4.025,0)node[circ];
\draw (M3.drain) -- (M6.drain);
\draw (M7.drain) -- (Mn2.drain) |-(M4.gate);
\draw (Mn0.gate) -- (Mn1.gate)-- (Mn2.gate);
\draw (Mn0.drain) |- (M1.source)-- (M2.source);
\draw (Mn1.drain) |- (M3.source)-- (M4.source);
\draw (M1.drain) -- ++(0,0.25)-- ($(M4.drain)+(0,0.25)$)--(M4.drain);

\draw (Mn0.source) node[right]{$Mn_0$}
  (Mn1.source) node[right]{$Mn_1$}
  (Mn2.source) node[right]{$Mn_2$}
  (M1.base) node[right]{$M_1$}
  (M2.base) node[left] {$M_2$}
  (M3.base) node[right] {$M_3$}
  (M4.base) node[left]{$M_4$}
  (M5.base) node[left]{$M_5$}
  (M6.base) node[right]{$M_6$}
  (M7.base) node[right]{$M_7$};

\draw (Mn0.source) node[ground]{};
\draw (Mn1.source) node[ground]{};
\draw (Mn2.source) node[ground]{};
\draw (M5.source) -- ++(5.5,0) node[anchor=south] {$V_{DD}$} -| (M7.source);

\draw (M1.gate) node[circ] node[left] {$Y_{2}$}
  (M2.gate) node[circ] node[right]{$Y_{3}$}
  (M3.gate) node[circ] node[left]{$Y_{1}$}
  (M7.drain) node[circ] node[right]{$X$}
  (Mn0.gate) node[circ] node[left]{$V_b$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Your example fails because some definitions are missing: `\figHT`, `ocirc`. Could you test it and solve the problems?

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified my code and deleted the definition of figHT. ocirc works fine in my code without any def though. Anyway, I changed it to circ. It's not extremely relevant for my question.

Comment: I developed the \whereami macro precisely for this problem.  See http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/cheap.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `perpendicular intersection` (`|-`, `-|`) coordinate system to place nodes.
If you want `X` point in intersection of `M4.gate` and `M7.drain` you can use:

```
\node[circ, label=right:$X$] at (M4.gate-|M7.drain) {};
```

As you can see from previous command, it's not necessary to declare two nodes, one for the `circ` and one for the `label`, because both can be combined in only one.

You can also use the same system to place elements:

```
\node[pmos, anchor=source] (M7) at (M4.gate-|M2.drain) {};
```

and read `TiKZ` documentation about `positioning` library (section 17.5.3 in version 3.0).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works just great. The really important command is the perpendicular intersection one. Not only is it useful for nodes, but also for connections. Thanks again.

Comment: @Basil1402 Glad to help you. If my answer was useful you consider accepting and/or upvoting it. take a look at [Why is voting important?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)